# How to right SQL query for this:

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me with SQL query to get table containing list of clients, sums of their purchases and their phones taking into account the following conditions:

1. First purchase was not earlier than 2017
2. Client made more than 3 purchases since 2017

I have the following tables:

```
1 purchases:

    1.1. purchase_id
    1.2. user_id
    1.3. purchase_date
    1.4. price

2 users:

    2.1. user_id
    2.2. phone
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Your data doesn't appear to make any sense either I'm afraid. What does your data actually look like, and what are the results you are after?

Answer (score 1):

Join em, and group on the user fields.

And with a `HAVING` it can filter on the total purchases and a minimum purchase date in 2017 and beyond.

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.phone, 
 SUM(p.price) AS TotalPurchasePrice
FROM users u
JOIN purchases p ON p.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id, u.phone
HAVING COUNT(p.purchase_id) > 3 
   AND MIN(p.purchase_date) >= CAST('2017-01-01' AS DATE)
```

Comment: Uhm, sorry. But I'll have to review it later when I got time.  When I now look back on question, the current query doesn't consider the "first" purchase to be after 2016.

Comment: @AnastasiaKolomina Fixed.  I moved the criteria for the purchase date from the WHERE to the HAVING.

Answer (score 1):

At a total guess, I suspect that this is *actually* what you are after, but sample data and expected result would make this a lot easier:

```
SELECT u.user_id,
       u.Phone,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.purchase_date >= '20170101' THEN Price END) AS TotalPrice
FROM users u
     JOIN purchases p ON u.user_id = p.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id,
         u.phone
HAVING MIN(p.purchase_date) >= '20170101'
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN p.purchase_date >= '20170101' THEN 1 END) > 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with sql-server, but in typical SQL you can do as follows. Hope this helps.

```
with query1 as (
    select
        users.user_id,
        min(phone) as phone,
        min(purchase_date) as first_purchase,
        sum(price) netpurchase,
        count(distinct purchase_date) counttxn
    from users
    join purchases
        on users.user_id = purchases.user_id
    group by users.user_id
)

select * from query1
where first_purchase >= date('2017-01-01') and counttxn > 3
```

The above query should take both your conditions into account.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest query is:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.Phone, SUM(Price) AS TotalPrice
FROM users u JOIN
     purchases p
     ON u.user_id = p.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id, u.phone
HAVING MIN(p.purchase_date) >= '2017-01-01' AND
       COUNT(*) > 3;
```

The first `HAVING` condition checks that the earliest purchase date is 2017-01-01 or later.  The second checks that there are at least three purchases.  Actually, this assumes that `users.user_id` is unique -- but that is a reasonable assumption.